# How to clear Nx cache

Tags: javascript, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx.dev

I have an Nx monorepo (https://nx.dev).
It has a folder with Nx cache (`./node_modules/.cache/nx/`).
Its size for now is over 3GB.

Is there a command for clear this cache?

Answer (score 103):

`nx reset` clears the cache.

Docs on `nx reset`: https://nx.dev/nx/reset#reset

Docs on the cache here: https://nx.dev/using-nx/caching#local-computation-caching

The above answer `nx clear-cache` is for the jest cache. I would comment but no rep :)

Comment: there you have enough rep now :)

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 79):

Just delete the whole 'nx' cache folder:

```sh
rm -rf ./node_modules/.cache/nx
```

Comment: I have some tests that get stuck from time to time and this is the only thing that get things working again

Answer (score 35):

This works in the latest version as of today (February 12, 2022). I am uncertain why this is no longer in the CLI documentation despite evidence of it being there in the past: [https://nx.dev/cli/clear-cache](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjHrLa4uvr1AhVAlWoFHSS6Ct4QFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnx.dev%2Fp%2Fr%2Fcli%2Fclear-cache&usg=AOvVaw14OUDhVLBKG_kcdtqaZky9)

`nx clear-cache`

Comment: `nx help` prints: `nx reset - Clears all the cached Nx artifacts (...) [aliases: clear-cache]`. But `reset` is not in the CLI documentation either.

Comment: [https://nx.dev/cli/reset](https://nx.dev/cli/reset) works so perhaps there was a rename (with backward compatible alias).

Comment: @JoeChung, thanks for your answer. I tried many examples but couldn't make the build successful due to the cache. after clearing the cache build works fine.

Answer (score 12):

There is not really any command to delete the Nx cache except to [skip it](https://nx.dev/latest/react/core-concepts/computation-caching#skipping-cache) or use the following command.

`npx nx run build --skip-nx-cache`

`npx nx run test --skip-nx-cache`

If size of the directory is your problem then may be running your node script as a cron job might be an option. In case, location of the directory is your concern then you also configure it and move it outside `node_modules` [like this](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2883#issuecomment-617148025).

Comment: The link for "skip it" doesn't seem to reference anything regarding the ability to skip the cache?

Answer (score 4):

I have implemented such a solution, but do not find it convenient.
Perhaps NX has a command to clear its cache, but I did not find it.

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "nx": "nx",
    "postnx": "node checkAndClearCache.js",
  ...
```

**checkAndClearCache.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const rimraf = require('rimraf');
const getSize = require('get-folder-size');

const cachePath = 'node_modules/.cache/nx';
const maxCacheMb = 2048;

if (fs.existsSync(cachePath)) {
  getSize(cachePath, (err, size) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    const MBSize = (size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2);

    console.log(`*** NX cache size is ${MBSize} Megabytes`);
    if (MBSize > maxCacheMb) {
      console.log('*** CLEAR NX CACHE ***');
      rimraf.sync(cachePath);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you can simply use `nx reset` to clear the cache, if you want to write a script to do it manually at last try to remove the older cache files